# use meshgrid for rows with common values in column

Tags: python, pandas

my dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [7, 8, 8]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [5, 8, 8]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df1,df2:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  2  3
2  7  8  8

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  2  3
2  5  8  8
```

I want to combine rows from columns `a` from both df's in all sequences but only where values in column `b` and `c` are equal.
Right now I have only solution for all in general with this code:

```
x = np.array(np.meshgrid(df1.a.values, 
  df2.a.values)).T.reshape(-1,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
    print(df)
   0  1
0  1  1
1  1  4
2  1  5
3  4  1
4  4  4
5  4  5
6  7  1
7  7  4
8  7  5
```

expected output for `df1.a and df2.a` only for rows where `df1.b==df2.b and df1.c==df2.c`:

```
   0  1
0  1  1
1  1  4
2  4  1
3  4  4
4  7  5
```

so basically i need to group by common rows in selected columns `b`and `c`

Comment: Are df1 and df2 of same size?

Comment: Your data creation and display don't match

Comment: yes, always, expected output has been edited

Comment: Why is it 1 1 and 1 4 in expected output? Why not just 1 1?

Comment: ah right, i will edit input again, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) using inner merge:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['b', 'c'])[['a_x', 'a_y']]

   a_x a_y
0   1   1
1   1   4
2   4   1
3   4   4
4   7   5
```

Comment: seem to be ok, simply one! but i would replace left_on & right_on with only `on=['a','b']` because columns are same. thanks

Comment: Did you mean `on=['b', 'c']`?